# How to use a php proxy to load a site into a iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, web

I try to load a random page which I set in my URL, into an iframe. Let's say I try to load "https://www.google.de" in an iframe.

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $_GET['URL'];?>" width="600" height="500"></iframe>
```

This is how I set the URL:

```
localhost/test/index.php?URL=https://www.google.de
```

Only a blank page is loaded. I know the reason for this is that Google is sending an "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" response header.

However, I try to find a way to load it anyway, someone told me to use a PHP Proxy script to do this, but I researched and found nothing helpful yet.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You may want to use a modern way instead of using `<iframe>`

Comment: Can you tell me more? Where can i learn a better way?

Comment: PHP proxy is a way, just JS proxy like XHook is another way

Comment: You were talking about that `<iframe>`is obsolete, so what is the modern alternative?

Comment: iframe of course is fading out.

Comment: then what should i use instead of iframe???

Comment: AJAX loading of contents have been used for years to replace iframe.

Comment: Finally an answer which i can use, +1 if someone show me where i can learn it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this script uncomment the proxy lines if you are behind any proxy server and want to bypass it using the authentication the proxy url, domain, username, password.

I used `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` Since I was calling this script from a different domain.

#### File: proxyscript.php

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    echo get_page($_GET['url']);
    //echo get_page("http://www.google.com");
    function get_page($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        /*
        $proxy = 'http://proxy.company.com:8080';
        $proxyauth = 'domain\proxy_username:proxy_password';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyauth);
        */
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

#### File: index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function getURL(url){
                document.getElementById('frame').src 
                   = 'path/to/proxyscript.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(url);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="getURL( 'http://www.google.com')">Google</button>
        <iframe id="frame" src=""></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will open google, but how can i open it in an iframe?

Comment: Start with `$url = $_GET['URL'];` and for iframe source use `localhost/test/proxy.php?URL=https://www.google.de`. Of course, the URL parameter should be [encoded](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php): `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de`.

Comment: The button method works, thx for that! But i try to load the iframe without pressing a button. I need to take the `url`via the GET Method from the URL.

Comment: You need to escape the url when you pass it as a param. Use some php to encode the url inside the arc attribute

Comment: Do you know where i can learn this? I have no idea on how to encode the url, and what is the `arc` attribute?

Comment: I was able to "solve" it with this code:
http://www.pasteall.org/61084/php

But there is a problem, it seems to only work for `www.google.de`, if i try `https://www.google.de`, then it loads a blank site again.

Comment: And some images are not loaded properly + if i press a button inside the google page loaded by iframe, then i get the error "Object not found - 404 error". But i guess this is another problem which requires an extra topic.

Comment: This is for HTTP I am not sure how to load up https. Maybe you can google around this.