# PHP Proxy for https requests

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, proxy

I already asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497865/how-to-use-a-php-proxy-to-open-google-in-an-iframe) about how to use a php proxy to load a website like www.google.de, into an iframe.

That worked somewhat with **http** protocol, but most pictures could not be loaded. It failed completly with https.

Is it possible to create a PHP Proxy which loads `https`and `http` websites into an iframe correctly, with no fails?

Comment: have you tried `//google.de` instead of `http://www.google.de` or `https://www.google.de`?

Comment: I need to load it with `https://www.google.de`. And //google.de did not work, it loads a blank page. The reason for this is that Google is sending an `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` response header, therefore i need a PHP Proxy which loads the site for me and gives me the result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. You have to download [glype](https://www.glype.com/) and call `browse.php` with your encoded URL as Get Parameter. This worked, but unfortunattely this software is not free to use it commercially.